# I want to delete row from both table

Tags: mysql

If i fire query to delete, it deletes only from one table not to both .
please help me find solution . given below the query i have tried.

```
DELETE m.* FROM master m
INNER JOIN field f ON m.id = f.label_id
WHERE f.id='13'
```

Mater table is deleting but not in case of field table.

Comment: use constrains and  delete cascade

Comment: you mean to say  make f.label_id to foreign key of master.id ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to delete entries from both tables `m` and `f` out of
   joined results:

   ```
   DELETE m,f FROM master m
   INNER JOIN field f ON m.id = f.label_id
   WHERE f.id='13';
   ```
2. In order to delete entries from table `m` out of joined results:

   ```
   DELETE m FROM master m
   INNER JOIN field f ON m.id = f.label_id
   WHERE f.id='13';
   ```
3. In order to delete entries from table `f` out of joined results:

   ```
   DELETE f FROM master m
   INNER JOIN field f ON m.id = f.label_id
   WHERE f.id='13';
   ```

**Note:** A better method might be to put a foreign key constraint having the behavior `ON DELETE CASCADE`. But for that you need **InnoDb** as your storage engine.