# Why isnt my delete inner joins not working?

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to delete 2 tables using `inner join`. I have a `modifier_category` table which is the parent table and the `modifier_items` table which is the child.

The way they relate is the `modifier_categories` table primary id which is stored in the `cat_id` column matches the `cat_parent_id` in the `modifier_items` table.

I can only look up the `modifier_categories` table by an `item_id`.

When I run the delete query, only the row in  `modifier_categories` table gets deleted but nothing gets deleted in the `modifier_items` table.

Below is the query I am using:

```
 DELETE mc 
 FROM modifier_categories mc 
 INNER JOIN modifier_items mi 
 ON mi.cat_parent_id=mc.cat_id 
 WHERE mc.menu_item_id = 28560
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: If you want to do [Cascade Deletes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298405), then do them by creating those relationships. See that reference, the last half of it. You are not showing your schemas (do that with `show create table xyz` for each xyz). You are not telling your query to do anything in regards to deleting rows from the second table.

Comment: An analogy of what you are currently doing is this. You have a `people` table and a `pets` table. Among your 40 people there might be a guy named Paul. Now, join people to pets and when you are done, delete Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Schema:

```
drop table if exists people;
create table people
(   id int primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    gender char(1) not null
);
insert people (id,name,gender) values
(1,'Kathy','f'),(2,'John','m'),(3,'Paul','m'),(4,'Kim','m');

drop table if exists pets;
create table pets
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    ownerId int not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    color varchar(100) not null,
    foreign key `fk_pets_2_people` (ownerId) references people(id)
);
insert pets(ownerId,name,color) values 
(1,'Rover','beige'),(2,'Bubbles','purple'),(3,'Spot','black and white'),
(1,'Rover2','white');
```

Queries:

```
DELETE p1 
FROM people p1
JOIN pets p2
ON p2.ownerId = p1.id
AND p1.name = 'Paul';
-- error 1451: FK violation (you would orphan poor Spot, left to feed himself)
-- and your constraint said not to do that


DELETE p2
FROM people p1
JOIN pets p2
ON p2.ownerId = p1.id
AND p1.name = 'Paul';
-- Spot is now gone

select * from pets;
+----+---------+---------+--------+
| id | ownerId | name    | color  |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | Rover   | beige  |
|  2 |       2 | Bubbles | purple |
|  4 |       1 | Rover2  | white  |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
```

Reload data, then.

```
DELETE p1,p2
FROM people p1
JOIN pets p2
ON p2.ownerId = p1.id
AND p1.name = 'Paul';

-- 2 rows deleted Spot is now gone
select * from people;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | gender |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Kathy | f      |
|  2 | John  | m      |
|  4 | Kim   | m      |
+----+-------+--------+

select * from pets;
+----+---------+---------+--------+
| id | ownerId | name    | color  |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | Rover   | beige  |
|  2 |       2 | Bubbles | purple |
|  4 |       1 | Rover2  | white  |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
```

As mentioned in the example in comments under the question, look into Cascade Deletes for your particular situation, if relevant.

Your query (is this what you meant to do?)

```
DELETE mi
FROM modifier_categories mc 
INNER JOIN modifier_items mi 
ON mi.cat_parent_id=mc.cat_id 
WHERE mc.menu_item_id = 28560;
```

Comment: Hi Drew. Thanks a lot for the example. The query you specified only deleted the row in the modifier_items table, but not in the modifier_category table. 

I found a solution that works below..

Comment: Ok, then an upvote shows I was helpful. That is how we roll here.

Answer (score 1):

I was suppose to explicitly specify both tables I wanted to perform the delete on. This code worked:

```
$query = "DELETE modifier_categories,modifier_items FROM modifier_categories  INNER JOIN modifier_items ON
modifier_items.cat_parent_id = modifier_categories.cat_id WHERE  modifier_categories.menu_item_id = $item_id ";
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete records from `mc` table (out of the joined results)

```
 DELETE mc 
 FROM modifier_categories mc 
 INNER JOIN modifier_items mi 
 ON mi.cat_parent_id=mc.cat_id 
 WHERE mc.menu_item_id = 28560
```

In order to delete records from `mi` table (out of the joined results)

```
 DELETE mi 
 FROM modifier_categories mc 
 INNER JOIN modifier_items mi 
 ON mi.cat_parent_id=mc.cat_id 
 WHERE mc.menu_item_id = 28560
```

In order to delete records from both `mc` and `mi` table (out of the joined results). Maybe you are looking for this

```
 DELETE mc,mi 
 FROM modifier_categories mc 
 INNER JOIN modifier_items mi 
 ON mi.cat_parent_id=mc.cat_id 
 WHERE mc.menu_item_id = 28560
```

Please take a look at this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865811/i-want-to-delete-row-from-both-table/35865923#35865923).

Comment: I didn't notice the answers before being a part of it. :( . By the way,  +1 for the pets and people.

Comment: Nevermind me. I was in a crappy mood. +1 for the guy on the horse